# Core Data SQLite store becomes readonly after update

Tags: ios, core-data

I have had reports of users being unable to use an iOS app after updating via the App Store because the SQLite database in use by Core Data apparently becomes readonly. This occurs with a read/write persistent store that is kept in the `Documents` folder of the app bundle.

The persistent store is created from scratch for each user the first time they log into the app. Its contents are maintained with a custom progressive managed object model migration. As it happens, there was no migration to perform for the most recent release, and thus the persistent store should be ready to open as soon as the app is launched.

The error that we received from the users is the same, and it happens early in the process launch after the upgrade completes. The `userInfo` of the `NSError` object is what we captured in this case:

```
NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 264;
NSUnderlyingException = "error during prepareSQL for SQL string 'SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA' : attempt to write a readonly database";
```

Due to some shortcomings in what we are logging and how we are managing the log files, I do not know precisely when this happens in the process of opening the persistent store. We are using `UIManagedDocument` but not sharing any documents via iCloud. I assume that the error occurs while opening an existing document package, but even that is a guess. (Because of this, I made improvements to the logging for future releases.)

The closest I have come to reproducing the error is to use the file permissions 0444 on the `persistentStore-shm` file in the document package of an iOS simulator app installation and then try the `SELECT` statement using the `sqlite3` command line interface. The error in that case is `SQLITE_CANTOPEN` rather than `SQLITE_READONLY`, so I am probably not on the right track with a theory about file permissions. From what I can tell, `UIManagedDocument` automatically fixes file permissions anyway.

What I am wondering is if anyone has experienced behavior similar to this? If so, is there any way to recover so that users do not have to go through the process of recreating the local data store?

Comment: Are you working with your database saved on the bundle?

Comment: Could it be that someone already works with the database (readwrite), while you try to use it (readonly due earlier readwrite)?

Comment: @washloops The database is not included with the bundle. It is built as the user interacts with the app and retrieves content from a server.

Comment: @JOM As far as I know, only the OS could be interacting with the database. My earliest suspicion was that the App Store upgrade process might somehow have been a factor, but I could not think of a way to prove that.

Answer (score 13):

Add your own descriptor to the options to (re)enable history tracking...

Do this before loading the store as part of the container set up:

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "YourDataStoreIdentifier" )
        
let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
// This allows a 'non-iCloud' sycning 
// container to keep track of changes 
// as if it was an iCloud syncing container

description?.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        
container.loadPersistentStores(...
```

Comment: This saved me. Great to know.

Comment: Way to go! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to this and it was rather puzzling. It turned out that the -shm file, the write-ahead log's index, had been cleared and needed to be rebuilt. This appears to happen automatically when loading the persistent store into an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

If you call `+[NSPersistentStore metadataForPersistentStoreWithURL:error:]` before doing that,  which I was doing, you'll get the error you reported and the return value will be `nil`.

So the solution that worked for me is to attempt to retrieve the metadata and, if that fails with an error, to load the persistent store into an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to rebuild the -shm. After doing that, calling `metadataForPersistentStoreWithURL:error:` will return the metadata without hitting the readonly error.

Comment: This is really interesting. Having a way to detect the need to rebuild the WAL index before opening the store is exactly what I need. I will look into this procedure as soon as I can. Thanks!